# What is the right way to do MVC using swift and getting data in background

Tags: ios, swift, model-view-controller, swift2

Short explanation :

I'm using NSNotificationCenter and make an Observer pattern, this work, imagine you have this architecture :

[image: MVC]

In the ViewController that manages the view :

In ViewDidLoad:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "initData:", name: "dataReady", object: nil)
    self.masterController.prepareData()
```

and

```
func initData(notif: NSNotification){
self.datas = self.masterController.getDatasReady()
}
```

(this is the observer pattern)

But I don't like this way, because I need to stock my data from my server in "global" in my DAO because I get the datas in Background and this return nothing most of the time.

Is there for you a better way to implement this ? MVC + get datas from server in background (I use dispatch_async for the background tasks).

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try delegates but delegation is used to send messages to a single known recipient acting on behalf of the sender. So if you have only one client for notification you can try it otherwise `NSNotificationCenter` is good choice.

Also I'd recommend check out something about [reactive programming](https://medium.com/swift-programming/reactive-swift-3b6050375534) maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: This article about reactive programming seems very interesting thanks !!